# Swift 2 - Timed Actions one second apart?

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I'm trying to get output like so:  
1  
                        (then a one second delay)  
Hello  
2       
                   (then a one second delay)  
Hello  
3       
                   (then a one second delay)  
Hello

But instead I get  
 
1  
2  
3  
        (then a one second delay)  
Hello  
Hello  
Hello

Here's my for loop invoking the NSTimer

```
    var timer = NSTimer()

    for i in 1...3 {
        print("\(i)");
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(MainVPScreenViewController.printTest), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }
```

And here's the selector method:

```
func printTest() {
    print("Hello")
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide

Comment: what's your interpretation of the problem? what do you think the cause is?

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution without NSTimer:

```
var i = 1

func printHello() {

    print(i)

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        print("Hello")
        i +=1
        if i <= 3 {
            printHello() 
        }
    }

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    printHello()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I need 2 `NSTimers` to do this, this is my approach

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var i = 1

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        beginPrinting()
    }

    func beginPrinting() {
         var timer2 = NSTimer()
        if(i <= 100)
        {
             timer2 = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.printWithDelay), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        }
    }

    func printWithDelay()
    {
        var timer = NSTimer()
        print("\(i)");
        i += 1
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.printTest), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }

    func printTest() {
        print("Hello")
        beginPrinting()
    }

}
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

Use timer with repeat to true. So in your view controller would be like this

```
var timer = NSTimer()
var counter = 0
var max = 10
let delay = 1 // in second

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(delay, target: self,
                                                selector: #selector(self.printTest), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func printTest() {
    counter += 1
    print(counter)
    print(hello)

    if counter == maxNumber {
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you all. They all worked for the problem as I stated it.  Unfortunately I tried to simplify my actual problem too much.  I have submitted another question with my actual problem.  But again thank you all.  Gil

Answer (score 0):

This does it with repeat false, and is set up to be in a playground:

```
import XCPlayground

XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

@objc class Foo: NSObject {
    static var timer = NSTimer()
    var i:Int

    override init() {
        Foo.timer = NSTimer()
        i = 1
    }

    func schedule() {
        print("\n\(i)");
        i += 1
        Foo.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0,
                                                       target: self,
                                                       selector: #selector(printTest),
                                                       userInfo: nil,
                                                       repeats: false)
    }

    @objc func printTest() {
        print("Hello")
        if i < 5 {
            schedule()
        }
    }
}
let bar = Foo()
bar.schedule()
```